# How to run Pip commands from CMD

Tags: python, cmd, pip

As I understand, Python 2.7.9 comes with Pip installed, however when I try to execute a Pip command from CMD (Windows) I get the following error:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When I type `python` I do get the following, which suggests it has been installed correctly:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I did however need to add some environmental variables to get the python part working on CMD:

- Add to the environment variable `PATH`: `"C:\Python27\"`
- Define the system variable `PYTHONPATH`: `"C:\Python27\"`

I cannot find a Pip folder within the Python directory, however there is a folder called "ensurepip" in `C:\Python27\Lib\`.

Does anybody know how can I get Pip commands to start working in CMD?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Little side note for anyone new to Python who didn't figure it out by theirself: [this should be automatic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYbw.png) when installing Python, but just in case, note that to run Python using the `python` command in Windows' CMD you must first add it to the `PATH` environment variable, as explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4621277/3889449)**.

If you have the Python launcher installed, in such case instead of typing `python` in the console you can type `py`. Whether or not one or both commands are available depends on the choices you made during installation.

---

To execute Pip, first of all make sure you have it installed, so type in your CMD:

```
> python
>>> import pip
>>>
```

The above should proceed with no error. Otherwise, if this fails, you can look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1) to see how to install it. Now that you are sure you've got Pip, you can run it from CMD with Python using the `-m` (module) parameter, like this:

```
> python -m pip <command> <args>
```

Where `<command>` is any Pip command you want to run, and `<args>` are its relative arguments, separated by spaces.

For example, to install a package:

```
> python -m pip install <package-name>
```

Comment: python -m pip install
/usr/bin/python: pip is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: What is the "-m"

Comment: @MadmanLee "m" stands for module, it launches a module executing it as a script rather than importing it.

Comment: python -m pip <command> <args> and python -m pip install <package-name>  are the only way to go.  I use Windows. Mac and Unix.  For some reason invoking pip is often slightly different -- unless it is called by the python command line with -m (module).   I could not remember the nuances, so I quit trying to run pip at the command line and I always run it as a python module.

Comment: in vscode on Win 10, 2024, i had to use `py -m pip install 
prompt_toolkit`

Answer (score 36):

Newer versions of Python come with `py`, the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows), which is always in the `PATH`.

Here is how to invoke `pip` via `py`:

```
py -m pip install <packagename>
```

`py` allows having several versions of Python on the same machine.

As an example, here is how to invoke the `pip` from Python 2.7:

```
py -2.7 -m pip install <packagename>
```

Comment: is there a way to just call "pip" instead of preceding with "py -m" ?
do i need to update PATH or something? or just create an alias?

Comment: @AkinHwan, you would have to add it to the `PATH`, because only the `py` command is exposed by default. It makes sense since you could have several versions of Python on your computer, `py` allows you to select the one you want.

Answer (score 29):

Make sure to also add "C:\Python27\Scripts" to your path. pip.exe should be in that folder. Then you can just run:

```
C:\> pip install modulename
```

Comment: If you work behind a firewall you may need to include your proxy server as an argument to your pip command.
pip --proxy YourProxyUrl:81 install pythonnet

Answer (score 6):

Go to the folder where Python is installed .. and go to Scripts folder .

Do all this in CMD and then type :

> `pip`

to check whether its there or not .

As soon as it shows some list it means that it is there .

Then type

```
pip install <package name you want to install>
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution that worked for me is, set the path of python in environment variables,it is done as follows

1. Go to My Computer
2. Open properties
3. Open Advanced Settings
4. Open Environment Variables
5. Select path
6. Edit it

In the edit option click add and add following two paths to it one by one:

```
C:\Python27

C:\Python27\Scripts
```

and now close cmd and run it as administrator, by that pip will start working.

Answer (score 4):

> Firstly make sure that you have installed python 2.7 or higher

Open Command Prompt as administrator and change directory to python and then change directory to Scripts by typing cd Scripts then type pip.exe and now you can install modules 
Step by Step:

- Open Cmd
- type in "cd \" and then enter
- type in "cd python2.7" and then enter

> ***Note that my python version is 2.7 so my directory is that so use your python folder here...***

- type in "cd Scripts" and enter
- Now enter this "pip.exe"
- Now it prompts you to install modules

Answer (score 2):

## This is the simplest way.

Within Command Prompt:

```
py -m pip install <ModuleNameGoesHere>
```

This will run anywhere as long as you have python installed.

**Breakdown:**

- `py` is a universal python command for most versions of Python. Which is nice because you don't have to find and navigate to a specific or complex path.
- `-m` stands for module
- `pip` is the package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python
- `install` is the Pip command for installation
- `ModuleName...` is the placeholder for the module/package object you wish to download into python.

**Example:**

> `py -m pip install requests`
> or `py -m pip install pandas`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to install Flask. I wanted to run **pip install Flask** command. But when I open command prompt it I goes to C:\Users[user]>. If you give here it will say pip is not recognized. I did below steps

On your desktop right click Computer and select Properties

Select Advanced Systems Settings

In popup which you see select Advanced tab and then click Environment Variables

In popup double click PATH and from popup copy variable value for variable name PATH and paste the variable value in notepad or so and look for an entry for Python.

In my case it was **C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32**

Now in my command prompt i moved to above location and gave
**pip install Flask**

[image]