# Telegram Bot - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, pip

hello I'm a beginner @ learning python.I'm trying to make a chatbot in Telegram
but I'm constanly recieving an error and I don't know how to solve the problem .I've checked python in Command promp And it is installed (python 2.7)

```
 $ pip install-telegram-bot
 File "<stdin>", line 1
 $ pip install-telegram-bot
 ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Where do you try to run your script?

Comment: Python (command line)

Comment: You manage python from outside the installation.

Comment: You need to execute the command in `cmd` or `terminal` and not in your Python shell.

Comment: do u mean i should run it in python IDE? i did that too but again the same error..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Pip commands from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8548030/7976758

Answer (score 2):

You got a typo. Redundant dash.

Run `pip install telegram-bot`

[User Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages) how to install packages with `pip`.

*UPDATE*: You should not be running `pip` commands in python prompt. You should run them in **terminal**. Also you should not copy `$` sign.

*To sum up*:
Open Terminal -> run `pip install telegram-bot` -> open python -> you are good to go.

Comment: i just did that but again i recieved the same error

Comment: are you on mac or windows?

Comment: @apadana for whom the question is asked?

Comment: Sorry it was meant for @Kiana