# Pip not working in my system,

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am getting the following error while using pip command, in anaconda.

```
C:\Users\name>pip install xmlschema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ANACONDA2\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "C:\ANACONDA2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
  File "C:\ANACONDA2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
  File "C:\ANACONDA2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2355, in load
  File "C:\ANACONDA2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
  File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .serializer import serialize
  File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\serializer\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .htmlserializer import HTMLSerializer
  File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\serializer\htmlserializer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .. import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

I am having utils package, but still throwing ImportError: cannot import name utils

Comment: Is this due to missing of any dependency package for pip, since its showing

 from .. import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows there is no sudo command. You have to run the command line as administrator and run the pip commands from above without sudo.

Comment: Dose it mean pip command only works in administrator account in windows?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this commands to fix it:

```
 pip uninstall requests
 pip install --upgrade requests
```

if you have trouble about to execute pip command on windows, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd)

Comment: 'C:\Users\name>sudo pip uninstall requests
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

'C:\Users\name>sudo pip install --upgrade requests
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

I get this while using sudo.

Comment: mine is a windows 10 machine

Comment: please try without sudo.

Comment: @krezus 'code' pip uninstall requests 'code' is for uninstalling a package with pip right!

Comment: @arun please check that link added above for executing pip commands on windows. if your  python version has pip included then you should run your commands on cmd in python **path**.