# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Cant find pip file

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I have tried to install libraries using pip but my console doesnt recognize as a command. I checked the python/scripts folder and there was no ppip.exe in the folder. I reinstalled Python 3.6 a couple of times but I havent been able to use it. I tried it on another computer and pip installed itself with python 3.6.

I've seen answers that say to open a Python shell, then insert

> python -m pip install 'packagename'

but i tried this and the shell marked invalid syntax at the end of writing pip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Pip commands from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd)

Comment: You probably have to install `pip`. Take a look at the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for tips on how to install `pip`

Comment: Maybe a path problem

Comment: What OS? Just search for pip.exe, go to the directory and run from there to see if it works. If yes, check your system/environment path settings. If there is a problem, reinstall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if `pip` is installed the following will work for sure

open a python shell then

`import pip`

`pip.main(['install', 'packagename'])`

replace the *packagename* with the package you want to install

because of the path problem try to use *absolute paths* ( in windows beginning with drive letter i.e. `C:/.../.../pip.exe`). in batch script it is generally  good idea to use absolute paths. Alternatively check if your path has to be fixed : https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

( http://jelly.codes/articles/python-pip-module/ )

Operating systems search for executables in the *system path*. I.e. windows knows by default where its own executables are located because the directory is in the system path, however when new software is installed that contains executables like `pip` the system path has to be edited to inform windows ( or linux ) where the new executables are located. The path is an *environment variable*. This is also valid for other languages and programs like java ( [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation) ) ,...
Now your problem very likely is that the directory where the `pip.exe` executable is stored is not part of your windows path. This has to be fixed like in **https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html**, chapter **3.3. Configuring Python**

[How to run Pip commands from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd)

Comment: While this might help someone get something installed interactively and get them over the hurdle in the short term, it doesn't really help a person understand why pip isn't available on the command line or how to find it.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks, ralf. Although I would like to know why one method works and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

on linux(ubuntu)

```
#for default 
sudo apt install python-pip

#for version specific
python2.7
sudo apt install python2-pip
for 3.x
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

In some terminals try to use

```
$py -m pip install packagename
```

Of course you first have to import pip with

$import pip