# Import _constant_time from cryptography.hazmat.binding

Tags: cryptography

When importing _constant_time

I was getting attribution error:  _init.cffi_1_0_external_module

I decided to go check in _constant_time.
And what is discover is _constant_time is not a python module but rather a cpp compiled library. (.so) .

So how is python importing from   .so file?  Or is something missing in cryptographic package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [an answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/568262) on Russian StackOverflow, you need to install `cffi` module as well.

```
sudo easy_install -U cffi
```

or

```
sudo pip install -U cffi
```

And on Windows the syntax is more like:

```
python -m pip install -U cffi
```

(according to [How to run Pip commands from CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29817514/8890345))

`-m` is needed on Windows since Windows doesn't interpret "shebang" (`#!`) interpreter lines so pip can't be run directly as on Linux/BSD/Unix/whatever, but needs to be run from python. `-U` tells pip or easy_install to install latest version of `cffi` available.

[English version of linked Russian page](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&nv=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568054/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-init-cffi-1-0-external-module&xid=17259,15700023,15700122,15700124,15700149,15700186,15700190,15700201,15700214&usg=ALkJrhg1KwjjSt-JYk2uCjEPpmADO_VIdQ)

Comment: So we can import a .so cpp compiled library in python!