# Install GitHub Packages without PyPi

Tags: python, github, installation

I'm trying to install this [Python GoPro Remote Control API](https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-py-api) from GitHub.  It's installation instructions say to use PyPi to install it.  As I don't have PyPi, or anything like it as far as I know, installed on my computer, I was wondering if and how you could install something like this manually.  I'd prefer the most if there were just a certain folder I have to put something to install it, but if I have to use Windows Command Line, Powershell, or Python Command Line, I'd be fine with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You do have `pip` (the command/module name for the program to interact with PyPi) installed, at least if you are using [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html)+ (released March 2014) or [Python 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-477-backport-ensurepip-pep-453-to-python-2-7)+ (released December 2014). And if not it is high time to update.

Just do `python -m pip install goprocam` in a commandline.

The `-m` flag tells python to load the module `pip` and the following arguments are passed along to it.

Depending on your setup you might have to specify the full path to the Python executable.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29817447/4042267) for more ways to run `pip` from the Windows command line.

Comment: Do it where?  In Command Line?  Or is there some .exe that I'm suppose to run?

Comment: @ElliotThomas: Yes, in the command line. You might have to specify the full path to the Python executable instead of just writing `python`, but that depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

PyPi is the Python Package Index. It is an online repository of Python packages. It is not something you can download.

What the github page is saying is to download the package from PyPi.

This can be done using Pip. If you have Python, Pip comes with it. Otherwise download Python.

Then in windows command line enter

```
pip install goprocam
```

This command should automatically download the package from PyPi. 
You can also download the package from github, though it it will take a little more time. You need to download/install github, add it to your path and then call

```
pip install git+githttps://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-py-api.git
```

If you get a Pip is not recognized command you will need to add Pip to the environmental variables. This can easily be found online.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pypi, you can clone the repo and cd into it, and use goprocam module

```
from goprocam import GoProCamera, constants
```