# Having problems while trying to download kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am a new programmer and I wanted to develop an app using python. I found kivy and wanted to download it. I am using Visual Studio as my development habitat and whenever I tried to download kivy, it just didn't. I opened the command prompt and did as the tutorials said. Typed "pip", nothing happened. This led me to modify my python 3.7.3. But as I clicked on modify, it showed me that I already selected pip. I didn't know what to do. It would be much appreciated if someone replies. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "nothing happened" you mean something happened right. because there should be some text shown when you use any command in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running CMD from windows:

- You may try `python -m pip --help` to get the usage help.
- Just `pip` should show the help as well.

[How to run Pip commands from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29817514) provides a brief explanation on pip with windows CMD
And [kivy.org Installation on Windows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html) may provide you with the CMD command to install it.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

@MagnusO_O is right, but I would also like to mention that kivy isn't exactly tailored to new python developers... I would HIGHLY recommend that you start with pygame before you move on to kivy. Assuming that you have at least some grasp on python itself.

Pygame is MUCH simpler and more easy to understand than kivy. Assuming you have pip installed just type

```
pip install pygame
```

into cmd and let it download and you now have access to all of pygame.

Here are just a [few guides for new devs](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials) and the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/)