# How to use an installed pip3 package from the command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I made a test package and uploaded it to pypi here: 
https://pypi.org/project/martin-test-package-11122/0.0.1/

The code of my package's `__init__.py` file is this:

```
import os
import sys

print("inside martin's test pip package")

print("the script has the arg %s" % (sys.argv[1]))
```

When I run the file locally with `python3 __init__.py testArgument` it just prints the argument output as expected.

I installed my package with `pip3 install martin-test-package-11122==0.0.1` and verified it's installed by running pip3 freeze.

How can I run my installed package from the command line? I'm trying to call my installed package with a command like `python3 -m pip3 martin-test-package-11122 commandLineArg` to get the output from my `__init__.py` file like when  ran it locally. But this -m command just causes the error `/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3`

I've been googling to try and find this and the closest I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd) stackoverflow question, which says to run `python3` and `import pip3` but even trying that didn't work.

Comment: Why are you trying to execute the module `pip3`? Try `python3 -m martin-test-package-11122 commandLineArg`. If you want this to be an actual command to run instead of a module, look into `entry_points`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`-m` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) does exactly what you need. `pip3` by itself only installs modules, it doesn't run them (Python does). So, there's no such thing as a "pip3 package" because `pip3` is just an installer, and you could as well copy the files to the appropriate folders manually, but `pip3` automates this.

Since the name of the folder with the package is `example_pkg`, you should just execute:

```
python3 -m example_pkg commandLineArg
```

Comment: hmmm, if i try to run that command i get an error saying ```/usr/bin/python3: No module named martin-test-package-11122```

Comment: if i run ```pip3 --version``` i get ```pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)```

Comment: `pip` doesn't matter: it installed the package - and now its job is done. What's the name of the project's folder - where the `__init__.py` is?

Comment: they title of the folder where ```__init___.py``` is is example_pkg, i didnt change it from a tutorial i was following. my setup.py and folder structure are up to date and on github here  https://github.com/MartinBarker/pypi-package

Comment: @Martin, then try `python3 -m example_pkg`

Comment: that worked, guess i need to rename that folder to my package name. thx