# Editing PATH Variable to Properly Use Pip Install

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt

I'm trying to install Lasagne by following the instructions provided at https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne.  I am supposed to run the following two commands from the command prompt:

pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/master/requirements.txt

pip install https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip

I have no experience dealing with the command prompt, so I don't completely understand what is going on.
Whenever I run these commands, I get this error message: ***'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.***  I've been troubleshooting according to the responses on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) thread, but nothing's worked so far.

[Here is a picture of my PATH variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEl8i.png)

[Here is what happens when I run echo %PATH%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDDGK.png)

I'm not sure if my PATH variable is set up properly.  I only added 3 paths to the variable, but when I run `echo %PATH%`, there seems to be several more.  Not to mention, the last path seems to be cut off.  Could this be part of the problem?

As far as I know, I have the 32 bit version of Python 3.8.2 installed, but when I run the command `python` from the command prompt, it just opens the windows store and tells me to install python.  The author of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd) thread got the following output when he ran the `python` command on his computer:

`Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

Is it a problem that I'm not getting a similar output?  Does this indicate some sort of issue with the way I installed Python?  It seems to be working fine with PyCharm.

Sorry if this is a basic/repetitive question.  I am not very knowledgeable about how operating systems work, so this is a lot to wrap my head around.  I have no idea where to even start, so any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It looks like you have both python2.7 and python3 installed.  Use ```pip3 install ...```

Comment: FWIW your problem has nothing to do with trying to install this "lasagne" package, so you might consider editing your question to reflect that. It's just a question of what Python installations you have on your system and how to correctly modify your path to reflect that.

Comment: @ewong Thank you for your answer.  As far as I know, I don't have python2.7 installed.  The little section where I mentioned Python 2.7.9 was a reference to someone else's question on SO.  Sorry if that was unclear.  I tried ```pip3 install ...``` and it gave me the same issue.  Do I need to cd into a certain directory, or is that the purpose of the path variable?